# C# — Errors when doing many concurrent outgoing HTTP requests

Tags: c#, .net, linux, http, digital-ocean

I'm trying to do 25k+ concurrent outgoing `HTTP` requests that work correctly on my local machine (Running `Windows 10` with 8 cores and 16 threads, with 16GB of RAM) but timeout/error when ran from my Digital Ocean droplet running `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` (using 2vCPUs and 2GB RAM).

This is with a .NET (dotnet) Core console application in C#.

- My personal network has `~300mbps` download speed.
- The droplet has `~1gbps` download speed.

Droplet job works correctly when limiting concurrent HTTP requests to 5k (but start failing when trying with 7.5k+) instead of the desired ~25k.

As far as the Digital Ocean team informed me:

- There isn't a maximum number of outgoing concurrent `HTTP` requests in droplets.
- There is no maximum inbound bandwidth limit in droplets.

---

Response times are faster on the Droplet, so I would expect the opposite behavior.

CURL from the **Droplet**:
[image: CURL from the Droplet]

CURL from **Local machine**:
[image: CURL from Local machine]

---

The code consists on reading a huge database and generating batches of 25k items and doing a simultaneous request per each, then performing some other operations and updating those entries.

Request code:

```
public static class HttpUtils
{
  private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  public static async Task GetThing(string id)
  {
    try
    {
      var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://api.example.com/{id}");
      Console.WriteLine($"Success {id}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Failed request {id}:\n{ex.Message}");
    }
  }
}
```

Then I execute the batches:

```
var tasks = batch.Select(thing => HttpUtils.GetThing(thing.id));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

And these errors appear after a while running:

```
[ERR] Failed request XXXXXXXXX
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at collector_utils.HttpUtils.GetThing(String id) in /root/development/foo/bar/HttpUtils.cs:line 20
```

---

I tried to dispose the `HTTP` response after it's successful but it didn't help at all and at this point I don't know what else to try or where I'm hitting some kind of limit.

Could it be that as I have less threads available in the droplet and I'm queueing thousands of requests, the timeout counter starts at queue time and end up timing out the ones that could not yet be processed?

Comment: `at this point I don't know what else to try` Can you limit to 5k at a time instead?

Comment: @mjwills I am, but I would like not to as the API I'm hitting has time-based throttling implemented, so I need to be as quick as possible in order to avoid it.

Comment: If you run locally on WSL - do you experience the same issue? What specific droplet are you using?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` is a notoriously slow operation (since it locks). Does removing them make a difference?

Comment: Is it possible the service you are hitting you is rate limiting you since they track usage from all droplets (not just yours)?

Comment: Will try with WSL. The droplet I'm using is the 2vCPUs and 2GB RAM one. I'm actually using Serilog, but removing the logs does not make any difference. There is no rate limiting unless I keep slowly hitting the server for a while continuously as far as I see.

Comment: @mjwills it may be that as I have less threads available in the droplet and I'm queueing thousands of requests, the timeout counter starts at queue time and end up timeouting the ones that could not yet be processed?

Comment: I suspect a good part of it is that your droplet is very weak (welcome to the cloud!). If you run it on a better droplet does it act differently?

Comment: `it may be that` Definitely.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is going to be a threading issue and not bandwidth. Try upping both min and max threadpool sizes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @MindingData to what values do you suggest trying that?

Comment: Running locally, you can use Perfmon to check how many threads your app is using. Then you can tip the max over that (and the min somewhere near that) etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/performance-counters

Comment: urm... So essentialy your HttpClients are timing out. Yeah sure you can load up your IO fairly extremely, however if you cant process them in-time (either by hardware or OS, or threads, or what ever), they are going to start timing-out. You need to start identifying the bottle neck (yourself), whether its cpu, bandwidth, the thread pool, the network device, who knows what it is, but one thing it is not... is this code. Also id suggest using `IHttpClientFactory` to cancel out other possibly related or future issues

Comment: @MichaelRandall how do you suggest implementing `IHttpClientFactory`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @mjwills if you want to post an answer I can mark it correctly, as –technically– your diagnosis was correct, my droplet was too weak and was hanging the requests, which made them timeout

Comment: Nah, write it up yourself and mark it as the answer. Great to hear you got it working!

Comment: How did you determine if the droplet is too weak?

Comment: @Lee I did a couple of tests by upgrading to more threads & RAM, checking the timeouts, and then going back to the other configuration. Therefore I considered that to be the answer.